# Why my browser did not cannot show my Semantic UI CSS form

Tags: semantic-ui

I am creating a form and serve it on my localhost with a port of 3000.

Everything works fine except my browser cannot show the CSS code in my browser and I got this error

```
Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:3000/Semantic-UI-master/dist/semantic.min.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

What happened? When I clicked the html file, the CSS is working. I am so confused

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following snippet

```
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  type="text/css"
  href="http://localhost:3000/dist/semantic.min.css"
/>
```

It seems that your trying to include the stylesheet with `text/html`

Comment: I am a little bit confused. Because I already statically host my Semantic-UI-master through index.js by using node

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the code you are using to import the stylesheet in your js

Comment: Here is my code `<link  href="../Semantic-UI-master/dist/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`

Comment: Can you post the js code you are using to serve the SUI dist, if your using express can you post the code which serves it as static content.

Comment: Sure of course!
`app.use(express.static('src'))
app.use(express.static('Semantic-UI-master'));`

Comment: Have you tried viewing `http://localhost:3000/Semantic-UI-master/dist/semantic.min.css` in a browser? I think the url should be `http://localhost:3000/dist/semantic.min.css` because express serves the directory you pass so you don't need to include it in the url